# Drop a line in HTML when four images have been entered in the table

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I want to have a table that gets its entries from a database. I have all that working. All i need to do is when four entries have been added to the column i want it to drop down a line and keep going until all the entries in the database have been added to the table.

This is what i have so far:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3px">
    <c:forEach var="car" begin="0" items="${requestScope.carList}" varStatus="status">
        <tr>
           <td><a href='Home.jsp'><img src="images/${car.licence}.jpg" width="240px" height="250"/></a></td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
           <td> Licence:${car.licence}, Model:${car.model}, Make:${car.make} and Colour:${car.colour}</td>
           </tr>

     </c:forEach>
</table>
```

This just prints all the images down in a line. I need to make a loop or something that drops a line every four images. Something like 
          c:when test="${status.index % 4 == 0}"
             tr
       /c:when

Comment: This gives us roughly 15% of the information to actually help you with your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Kinda wild guessing here:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3px">
<c:forEach var="car" begin="0" items="${requestScope.carList}" varStatus="status">
<c:when test="${status.index % 4 == 0}">
<tr>
</c:when>
<td><table><tr><td><a href='Home.jsp'><img src="images/${car.licence}.jpg" width="240px" height="250"/></a></td></tr>
<tr><td> Licence:${car.licence}, Model:${car.model}, Make:${car.make} and Colour:${car.colour}</td></tr></table></td>
<c:when test="${status.index % 4 == 3}">
</tr>
</c:when>
</c:forEach>
</table>
```

Basically, test if it's the first entry of a group of four - if so, start a new row. If it's the fourth of a group of four, close the row. You will also need to close the row if it's the last entry and the entry cannot be divided by 4.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you just want to break every 4th td so you need **:nth-child** like so:

```
td:nth-child(4n) {clear: left}
```

[**FIDDLE THAT**](http://jsfiddle.net/Riskbreaker/Y5U3N/1/)

Though your code and ref does not help me understand what you really want so yes another wild guess..but since you tag has CSS...I figure I add this.